# Como resolver alinhamento no IE ao fazer style a um uib-accordeon?

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

Boas pessoal,

Estou a ter algumas dificuldades quando faço *styling* de um uib-accordion. Os resultados no Chrome/IE/Firefox são diferentes relativamente ao IE11. Como posso resolver isto?

Aqui está o meu HTML:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime ">
<div ng-repeat="menuElement in vm.menuElements" class ="parent-container" ng-init="parentIndex = $index">
    <div uib-accordion-group is-disabled="false">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            <div class="parent">
                <i class="{{menuElement.iconClass}}"></i>
                <a>{{menuElement.menu}}</a>
                <i class="go-right {{menuElement.iconClass}}"></i> 
            </div>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
    </div>
</div>
```

E o meu SASS:

```
.parent-container
    .panel
        background-color: transparent
        border: none

        .panel-heading
            background-color: transparent
            padding-left: 0px
            height: 35px

            .panel-title
                width: 100%

                .parent
                    align-items: center
                    display: flex
                    width: 100%

                    i
                        font-size: 2.2em
                    a
                        font-size: 14px

                .go-right
                    position: absolute
                    right: 0px
```

Resultados no Chrome/Edge/Firefox (que estão corretos):

[image]

Resultado no IE11:

[image]

Como é possível visualizar, o elemento que está a usar a classe 'go-right' está correto quando utilizo o Chrome/Firefox/Edge. No entanto, quando uso o IE, o resultado não é o mesmo.

Estou a tentar tudo para resolver este problema, mas por alguma razão o IE não está contente com o 'position: absolute' da classe 'go-right'. De notar que todos os items em cada div devem estar alinhados verticalmente, é por isso que estou a usar a propriedade display flex.

Obrigado deste já.

Comment: Tentou colocar um `top: 0`?

Comment: Já sim. Neste caso, o elemento vai para o elemento mais em cima (onde está o X)

Comment: Parece que falta um `position: relative` na classe `.parent`... o absolute precisa de um relative no elemento pai.

Comment: Não resolveu o problem com o position: relative

Comment: Se puder colocar na pergunta o código renderizado (CTRL+U no navegador) eu poderia dar uma olhada.